# Redirect user to mobile version of site

Tags: mobile, redirect, user-agent

How can i redirect users with older devices to a simplified (no css ) version of mobile site [ m.site.com  ] , and newer devices like Iphone or Samsung Galaxy to a more modern one ?
[sp.site.com ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend feature detection.

Test the features you need for the 'newer devices' and redirect to the older if there is a lack of support.

You can test features using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

redirection is as easy as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    window.location = "m.site.com"
//-->
</script>
```